# Linux bash: timeout a program if the program hangs in there and echo 'timeout'

Tags: linux, bash, grep, timeout

I have a program which will print out either pass or fail. I want to detect the programs which hang in there and echo 'timeout'

I wrote a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n 'test' && timeout 5 ./mytest | grep -q -i 'passed' && echo ', passed'|| echo ', failed'

if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then
    echo 'timeout'
fi
```

But it will treat the programs hang in there as 'failed' and kill the program. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

man timeout:

```
NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
       timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
       timeout [OPTION]

DESCRIPTION
   Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
...
```

Here's an example:

```
cmd_output=`timeout 5 ./mytest`

if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then
    echo 'timeout'
else
    echo $cmd_output
fi
```

Comment: Yes, it will kill the program, but it will echo 'failed' instead of 'timeout'. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Yes, you need to parse the return value of the "timeout" command and print the appropriate status.

Comment: I did wrote a if statement after that for getting the return value of timeout. But it echo 'failed' instead of 'timeout'.

Comment: How exactly are you checking for timeout? You should be checking for a return value of "124". That's what the timeout command returns when a timeout occurs. Is that what you did?

Comment: That's not the right way to do it. $? is the return value for the *last* command that was executed. Which is not the timeout command in this case (it's the echo).

Comment: So, how could I get the timeout return value for my case? Thanks!

Comment: You should avoid using old and deprecated back tics, use parentheses like this: `cmd_output=$(timeout 5 ./mytest)`

Answer (score 0):

The return code $? is getting lost because you combine several commands on one line. Break this line up:

```
echo -n 'test' && timeout 5 ./mytest | grep -q -i 'passed' && echo ', passed'|| echo ', failed'
```

The return code of commands combined with && and || is the last command run. In the failed case this command is echo ', failed'. The return code of this echo is 0. Additionally the return code of commands piped together is the last most return-code (controillable with 'set -o pipefail'). You can get the first (and all the other) return codes using the PIPESTATUS array in bash.
To illustrate:

```
# the droid you want
timeout 5 sleep 100
echo $?
124

# the droid you want is in ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
$ timeout 5 sleep 100 | grep -q -i 'passed'
Terminated
$ echo $? PIPESTATUS[0]=$PIPESTATUS all=${PIPESTATUS[@]}
143 PIPESTATUS[0]=124 all=124 143

# the droid you want is gone
$ timeout 5 sleep 100 | grep -q -i 'passed' && echo ', passed'|| echo ', failed'
Terminated
, failed
$ echo $? PIPESTATUS[0]=$PIPESTATUS all=${PIPESTATUS[@]} ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
0 PIPESTATUS[0]=0 all=0 0
```